# Dynamic SQL with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, db2

I want to build a dynamic query depending on the incoming request parameters.
I have a general query with a lot of sql statements.
But dependent on the incoming request parameter, some of the select statements could be skipped, meaning there is no need than to make a select on `Table A` for example.
I am using native query inside Hiberate, but is their any possibility to mark the line with a condition.

```
WITH 
A AS ( //take this only when we have a request parameter like astat = true
SELECT ID
FROM A
WHERE...),
B AS (
SELECT ID
FROM B
WHERE ...)
SELECT ID
FROM A
JOIN ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ID
FROM B
JOIN ...
```

Comment: Don't do it in SQL, switch in java between different SQL statements depending on the input. Logicaly you would only query with the SQL statements not interpet code.

Comment: There are if statements in SQL, try google ;)

Comment: Alternatively, you could take a look at the Java Criteria API.

Comment: As can I see there is no support for some sql constructs in CriteriaAPI.
What I want to have is that the evaluation of type check condition for the select is made before execution, types I will set custom before execution
`SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE 'a_type' in (types)`